# PHP - strftime output in another language is garbled

Tags: php, strftime

I have this code in PHP to translate dates to their locale

```
$date = time();
$locale_code = 'en_NZ';
$format_full_date = '%e %B %Y at %l:%M %P'; // 21 August 2013 at 3:26 am

// Set locale
setlocale(LC_ALL, $locale_code);

// Get date
$locale_date =  strftime(lang('format_full_date'), $date);

// Reset locale
setlocale(LC_ALL, 0);
```

This works fine in `en_NZ`. The output is something like `21 August 2013 at 8:26 pm`

But when I change locale_code to `fr_CA`, I get outputted `21 ao�t 2013 at 8:26`

There are two problems here

- Why is the French `August` translation garbled?
- Why is am/pm not showing?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing `strftime` outputs in a different encoding than your current Content-Encoding. Make sure they match or do a conversion. `utf8_encode`/`utf8_decode` might come in handy.

August in French is août.

Comment: Easiest way is to just use utf-8 for the page encoding, ie `<meta charset="utf-8">`

Comment: I don't want to jump to conclusions, but it is likely that `strftime` outputs in `utf8`; it might also be locale dependent.

Comment: I am already using `<meta charset="utf-8">` so it is not a solution.

Comment: If you have `iconv` installed, can you try `iconv_get_encoding()` on the output of `strftime`?

Comment: I don't think I have iconv installed since all it returns is `bool(false)`

Answer (score 0):

my suspicion is that it is to do with unicode encoding. Try this:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, $localecode);
echo utf8_encode(strftime(lang('format_full_date'), $date);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. However, I don't see the am/pm times still. Is that a locale thing?

Comment: @arvinsim French dont have words for am and pm (they use 'du matin' for a.m., 'de l'après-midi' from noon until about 6 p.m., and 'du soir from 6 p.m.' so my suspicion is that it is to do with that